# Making a list containing relevance number for every party_id in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need help making a list containing the relevance for every party_id.
Below is the dataframe, the only columns used in the dataframe is the first `new_party_id` and the `relevance` (located at the end of the dataframe)

My expected output: (The first list is for new_party_id `A09029493F` containing the `relevance` number and the second is `A09292791U`, and so on)

`[1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] ...`

```
+------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------+----------------+--------------+----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
|new_party_id|recent_purchase|      new_mcc_type|new_merch_store_code|merch_store_code|party_id_index|    rating|  party_id|            mcc_type|             mt_desc|relevance|
+------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------+----------------+--------------+----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
|  A09029493F|     2022-05-20|Bars & Restaurants|           168339858|       168327658|        557172|0.15998328|A09029493F|  Bars & Restaurants|CHILLIPADI       ...|        1|
|  A09029493F|     2022-05-20|Bars & Restaurants|           168339858|       168327659|        557172| 0.3183104|A09029493F|  Bars & Restaurants|CHILLIPADI       ...|        1|
|  A09029493F|     2022-05-20|Bars & Restaurants|           168339858|       168341944|        557172|0.19468163|A09029493F|  Bars & Restaurants|KOPI ONG         ...|        1|
|  A09029493F|     2022-05-20|Bars & Restaurants|           168339858|       168993276|        557172|0.28519514|A09029493F|        Supermarkets|SHENGSIONG@JURONG...|        0|
|  A09029493F|     2022-05-20|Bars & Restaurants|           168339858|       168351967|        557172|0.23260666|A09029493F|  Bars & Restaurants|KOUFU PTE LTD    ...|        1|
|  A09029493F|     2022-05-20|Bars & Restaurants|           168339858|       168993311|        557172|0.18300338|A09029493F|        Supermarkets|SHENGSIONG@BEDOKR...|        0|
|  A09029493F|     2022-05-20|Bars & Restaurants|           168339858|       900000315|        557172|0.71359485|A09029493F|Associations/ Mem...|NTUC-MSHIP FEE(RP...|        0|
|  A09029493F|     2022-05-20|Bars & Restaurants|           168339858|       168335402|        557172|0.14431615|A09029493F|  Bars & Restaurants|NTUC FOODFARE MBF...|        1|
|  A09029493F|     2022-05-20|Bars & Restaurants|           168339858|       168339482|        557172|0.21039693|A09029493F|        Supermarkets|PRIME SPKMT (1996...|        0|
|  A09029493F|     2022-05-20|Bars & Restaurants|           168339858|       900000157|        557172|0.48820275|A09029493F|           Utilities|SEMBCORP POWER PT...|        0|
|  A09292791U|     2022-05-27|           Apparel|           168337894|       168338797|        159266|0.20081769|A09292791U|        Supermarkets|PRIME SUPERMARKET...|        0|
|  A09292791U|     2022-05-27|           Apparel|           168337894|       168345244|        159266|0.18008989|A09292791U|  Bars & Restaurants|KOUFU PTE LTD    ...|        0|
|  A09292791U|     2022-05-27|           Apparel|           168337894|       168993322|        159266|0.21735035|A09292791U|        Supermarkets|SHENGSIONG@PUNGGO...|        0|
|  A09292791U|     2022-05-27|           Apparel|           168337894|       168993315|        159266|0.11500418|A09292791U|        Supermarkets|SHENGSIONG@CLEMEN...|        0|
|  A09292791U|     2022-05-27|           Apparel|           168337894|       168993269|        159266|0.16303009|A09292791U|        Supermarkets|SHENG SIONG-SS-F1...|        0|
|  A09292791U|     2022-05-27|           Apparel|           168337894|       168343844|        159266| 0.2214741|A09292791U|  Bars & Restaurants|KOUFU PTE LTD    ...|        0|
|  A09292791U|     2022-05-27|           Apparel|           168337894|       168339566|        159266|0.30556816|A09292791U|Land and Sea Tran...|COMFORT/CITYCAB TAXI|        0|
|  A09292791U|     2022-05-27|           Apparel|           168337894|       168339566|        159266|0.30556816|A09292791U|Land and Sea Tran...|COMFORT/CITYCAB T...|        0|
|  A09292791U|     2022-05-27|           Apparel|           168337894|       168993367|        159266| 0.2066507|A09292791U|        Supermarkets|SHENGSIONG@CLEMEN...|        0|
|  A09292791U|     2022-05-27|           Apparel|           168337894|       700013581|        159266|  0.331085|A09292791U|Entertainment & R...|ACTIVESG SPORT SI...|        0|
+------------+---------------+------------------+--------------------+----------------+--------------+----------+----------+--------------------+--------------------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

df1.groupBy("new_party_id").agg(`collect_list`(col('relevance')))

```
d1 = [
    ('A09029493F', 1),
    ('A09029493F', 1),
    ('A09029493F', 1),
    ('A09029493F', 0),
    ('A09029493F', 1),
    ('A09029493F', 0),
    ('A09029493F', 0),
    ('A09029493F', 1),
    ('A09029493F', 0),
    ('A09029493F', 0),
    ('A09292791U', 0),
    ('A09292791U', 0),
    ('A09292791U', 0),
    ('A09292791U', 0),
    ('A09292791U', 0),
    ('A09292791U', 0),
    ('A09292791U', 0),
    ('A09292791U', 0),
    ('A09292791U', 0),
    ('A09292791U', 0),
]

df1 = spark.createDataFrame(d1, ['new_party_id', 'relevance'])

df1.groupBy("new_party_id").agg(collect_list(col('relevance'))).show(100, False)
# +------------+------------------------------+
# |new_party_id|collect_list(relevance)       |
# +------------+------------------------------+
# |A09029493F  |[1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0]|
# |A09292791U  |[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
# +------------+------------------------------+
```